# how to store kinesis streams for playback

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

we have a use case where we need to continually record and merge kinesis streams for playback.

For example we would store 1 hour's worth of kinesis events, and then continually playback and overlay an hour's worth of future kinesis events on the same one hour timeline - repeated over and over again.

I'm thinking we can firehose the kinesis events to s3, perhaps have a bucket for each second or so and then have a process that reads all the events from each second and emit the events on playback.  Does that sound reasonable?

Is there a built in AWS feature I can use for this?

Comment: To give a good answer, it's necessary to understand what you want to do with the data. In particular, whether you need to group data by some part of the timestamp (in which case Firehouse is probably the wrong answer, since it accumulates as many records as it can). It's possible that DynamoDB would be a good fit (using a key based on the minutes/seconds from the timestamp).

Comment: we wouldn't do any grouping or transforms - just a raw playback of all events as they were recorded and played back as is

Comment: That isn't really helpful. I suggest trying your original idea of using Firehose. If it does what you want, great. If it doesn't, you'll be able to describe how your desired behavior differs from what it does.